# Can LINQ be used to search multiple lists in a single operation?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have some lists:

```
    KeyedCollection<int, InstantiatedObjectsListType> ActiveUnitList = new InstantiatedObjectListCollection();
    KeyedCollection<int, InstantiatedObjectsListType> ActiveBuildingList = new InstantiatedObjectListCollection();
    KeyedCollection<int, InstantiatedObjectsListType> ActiveUIList = new InstantiatedObjectListCollection();
    KeyedCollection<int, InstantiatedObjectsListType> ActiveManagersList = new InstantiatedObjectListCollection();

    KeyedCollection<int, InstantiatedObjectsListType> DisabledUnitList = new InstantiatedObjectListCollection();
    KeyedCollection<int, InstantiatedObjectsListType> DisabledBuildingList = new InstantiatedObjectListCollection();
    KeyedCollection<int, InstantiatedObjectsListType> DisabledUIList = new InstantiatedObjectListCollection();
    KeyedCollection<int, InstantiatedObjectsListType> DisabledManagersList = new InstantiatedObjectListCollection();
```

I want to check if an object is in any of these lists either by key, or by value. Can LINQ be used to search all 8 lists in a single operation, or will I need to use 8 separate operations in a chain?

I understand that I can have multiple operations to search one list at a time, though for the sake of neatness I would rather condense it into a single operation.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You won't get any appreciable performance improvements. Is there another reason?

Answer (score 3):

You can Union those lists and search the result.

```
ActiveUnitList
.Union(ActiveBuildingList)
.Union(ActiveUIList)
.Where(...)
```

Comment: `Contains` rather than `Where`, for OP's case. As a note, this operation is still `O(n)` (with `n` being the sum of the sizes) because of how yielding works.

Comment: Thank you, is there also a LINQ operation that can check each of the KeyedCollections via key instead of by value if I want? In some instances I will know the key, but not what list it will be in, vs knowing the value and not knowing what list it will be in.

Comment: Interestingly enough it seems when using union it seems to ignore that there is a key. Can't figure out if you can combine them like this, and then access via key.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider restructuring your code a bit to remove duplication and provide much faster lookup.

It looks like you have 4 types which can be Active or Disabled, so you should be able to put an interface on the 4 types:

```
 public interface IDisableable
 {
     bool IsActive();
 }
```

Then you could have a Dictionary to look everything up by Id

```
private Dictionary<int, IDisableable> disableableObjectsById;
```

And then getting the active objects is like this:

```
var activeObjectsWithId = disableableObjectsById.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.IsActive());
```

Depending on what else you are doing with the collections, you could have other interfaces that the objects use and other types of collection.